# Reference to self with Swift 4's KeyPath

Tags: swift, swift4, keypaths

Is there any way to reference `self` with Swift 4's new `KeyPath`s?

Something like this works fine, we can address a property of an object:

```swift
func report(array: [Any], keyPath: AnyKeyPath) {
    print(array.map({ $0[keyPath: keyPath] }))
}

struct Wrapper {
    let name: String
}

let wrappers = [Wrapper(name: "one"), Wrapper(name: "two")]
report(array: wrappers, keyPath: \Wrapper.name)
```

But addressing an object itself seems impossible to me:

```swift
let strings = ["string-one", "string-two"]
report(array: strings, keyPath: \String.self) // would not compile
```

I suppose there should be some obvious way for this?

**EDIT:**

Or simply:

```swift
let s = "text-value"
print(s[keyPath: \String.description]) // works fine
print(s[keyPath: \String.self]) // does not compile
```

Comment: @Sulthan It makes a perfect sense in scenario where we dealing with an array of arbitrary objects by specifying a keypath for they property that provides title, for example. By specifying a keypath to `self` – like we can in Objective-C – we can use instances of provided objects as their title.

Comment: I think the language should support "self keypaths" (with the exact syntax you're attempting to use, e.g `\String.self`), feel free to [file an improvement](https://bugs.swift.org) or [bring it up on the Swift forums](https://forums.swift.org). A while ago I built a strongly-typed wrapper around firebase database that worked with keypaths (so you could say things like `someProvider.observeValue(at: \.someProperty) { ... }`), and self keypaths would have been very useful to have (at the time I just hacked it by adding a computed property that just returned `self`).

Comment: @Hamish Damn me, it's the method! `extension String { var instance: String { return self } }` allows to use `\String.instance`. Write an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, this isn't something Swift keypaths currently support. However, I do think this is something they *should* support (with the exact syntax you're attempting to use, e.g `\String.self`). All expressions have an implicit `.self` member that just evaluates to the expression, so it seems like a perfectly natural extension to allow `.self` in keypaths (**Edit:** This is now [something that's being pitched](https://forums.swift.org/t/some-small-keypath-extensions-identity-and-tuple-components/13729)).

Until supported (if at all), you can hack it with a protocol extension that adds a computed property that just forwards to `self`:

```
protocol KeyPathSelfProtocol {}
extension KeyPathSelfProtocol {
  var keyPathSelf: Self {
    get { return self }
    set { self = newValue }
  }
}

extension String : KeyPathSelfProtocol {}

let s = "text-value"
print(s[keyPath: \String.description])
print(s[keyPath: \String.keyPathSelf])
```

You just need to conform types that you want to use "self keypaths" with to `KeyPathSelfProtocol`.

Answer (score 3):

Yes there is a way to reference `self` but it is not available in Swift 4. It was implemented for Swift 5 in september 2018 and it is called the [Identity key path](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0227-identity-keypath.md).

You use it like you suggested

```
let s = "text-value"
print(s[keyPath: \String.self]) // works in Swift 5.0
```

Even though Swift 5 is not yet released, you can already try it out by downloading a development version at: https://swift.org/download/#releases

Answer (score 0):

The behavior of `keyPath` is <strike>the same as</strike> similar to Key-Value Coding: Getting the value of a **member** of the class / struct by `key` subscription.

In Swift `self` is not a member of the class, `description` is.

What result would you expect with

```
report(array: wrappers, keyPath: \Wrapper.self)
```

Comment: Actually you *can* do `obj.value(forKey: "self")` on an Objective-C object, so the behavior is not completely the same.

Comment: @MartinR OK, I slightly changed the phrasing. 

Comment: @vadian Yes, i know that `self` is not a property of Swift's class or struct. I'm looking for a method to receive the same instance of object that I'm applying key path to.

Comment: I am afraid you can't with `keyPath`

Comment: It's sad. That was an elegant pattern in Objective-C. So... It seems that I have to embrace an object wrappers. :)

Comment: All expressions have an implicit `self` member though (that just evaluates to the expression), for example you can say `let s = "foo"; print(s.self)`. It seems like a perfectly natural extension to allow `.self` in key paths.